# How to calculate the cv function of a random sample

Tags: r

I had to create a `cv` function in r then use it to answer a question:
"Compare the CV’s for two uniform random samples, `runif(100, min=0, max=1)` and `runif(100, min=0, max=10)`."

Answer (score 0):

We could use the `cv` function from one of the packages

```
library(EnvStats)
cv1 <- cv(v1)
cv2 <- cv(v2)
```

By default, the `method` used is "moments" and the `sd.method` as "sqrt.unbiased" which is basically

```
sd(v1)/mean(v1)
sd(v2)/mean(v2)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(1)
v1 <- runif(100, min=0, max=1)
v2 <- runif(100, min=0, max=10)
```